# CMake EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL argument ignored when running 'make all'

Tags: cmake

### Introduction

Using CMake, I am trying to build a library using a special `make` target. To this end, I use the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` argument to ensure that the library is not built by running `make` (which defaults to `make all`). Unfortunately, the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` option seems to be ignored by `cmake`.

Consider the following file tree:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── foo
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── headers
│   │   └── foo.h
│   └── src
│       └── foo.cpp
└── src
    └── main.cpp

4 directories, 5 files
```

In this file tree, you can see that I basically have two parts:

1. The foo library, for which all files are located in `./foo/`.
2. The main executable, for which the source code is located in `./src/main.cpp`.

Below, I will further explain these two parts and the behaviour I am observing.

### The foo library

First of all, the header code located in `./foo/headers/foo.h` is:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

#include <iostream>

void foo(void);

#endif // _FOO_H_
```

The corresponding source code, located in `./foo/src/foo.cpp`, is:

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void) {
    std::printf("Hello foo!\n");
}
```

As you can see, the foo library only contains the function `foo()`. This function simply prints `Hello, foo!` to the terminal. To build the foo library, I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file defined (in `./foo/CMakeLists.txt`):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(foo
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

# Create a foo library target
add_library(foo EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
    "src/foo.cpp"
)

target_include_directories(foo
    PUBLIC "headers"
)
```

Note that I use the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` argument in the `add_library()` function.

To test the behaviour of the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` argument, I will now build the foo library as a stand-alone (using the previously shown `CMakeLists.txt`). Starting from the top directory (`.`), I use the following workflow:

```
$ cd foo
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

After this is finished, I run the `make` command:

```
$ make
(nothing happens)
```

As expected, nothing happens (since the foo library is excluded from the `all` target). Now, when I use `make foo`, I get the following output:

```
$ make foo
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/foo.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libfoo.a
[100%] Built target foo
```

So far, so good. Before moving on to building the main executable, I completely remove the `./foo/build` directory and go back to the top-level directory:

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf build
$ cd ..
```

### The main executable

The source code for the main executable is located in `./src/main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(TestProject
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

# Include the foo library
add_subdirectory("foo" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# Create the main executable
add_executable(TestProject
    "src/main.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(TestProject
    PRIVATE foo
)
```

Note that I again use the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` argument, but now for the `add_subdirectory()` function.

To generate a makefile for the main executable, I use the following workflow:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

When I now run `make`, I get the following output:

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target foo
[ 25%] Building CXX object foo/CMakeFiles/foo.dir/src/foo.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libfoo.a
[ 50%] Built target foo
Scanning dependencies of target TestProject
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable TestProject
[100%] Built target TestProject
```

As you can see, it first builds the foo library. However, this is not what I expected! I explicitly stated to exclude the foo library from the `all` target. Hence, I would expect the need to first run `make foo` before running `make`.

This brings me to my main question(s): does someone know why it ignores the `EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL` option in the `add_subdirectory()` function in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`? It did work when I built the foo library as a stand-alone. Is this a bug in `cmake`? If not, how do I achieve my expected behaviour (i.e. the need to run `make foo` before running `make`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug. CMake does not include the `foo` lib in the all target directly. It does however add the `foo` target as dependency to `TestProject` and since `TestProject` is included in the `all` target, `foo` gets built too, if you build `all`.

This needs to be done this way. How else would you be able to link the `foo` function into `TestProject`?

If you want to use a lib that is not built as part of `all`, you need to use a [imported lib](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries). Doing this is and including the lib in the project seems a bit nonsensical though, but here you go.

```
add_library(foo STATIC EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL
    "src/foo.cpp"
)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(TestProject
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

# Include the foo library
add_subdirectory("foo" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

# Create the main executable
add_executable(TestProject
    "src/main.cpp"
)

# add copy of foo as imported lib
add_library(foo_imported STATIC IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(foo_imported INTERFACE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)
set_target_properties(foo_imported PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION $<TARGET_FILE:foo>)


target_link_libraries(TestProject
    PRIVATE foo_imported
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I tried replacing my top-level CMakeLists.txt with your version and adding the 'STATIC' specification to the add_library() function, but unfortunately it gives me an error during configuration time: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (target_include_directories): Cannot specify include directories for imported target "foo_imported". Would you happen to know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: I managed to get around the previous problem by changing the line `target_include_directories(foo_imported INTERFACE $<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>)` to `set_property(TARGET foo_imported APPEND PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>")`. Currently, the cmake configuration works. However, when running the generated makefile, it keeps giving me the following error: `CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/build.make:93: *** target pattern contains no '%'`.